# configure: WARNING: FFTW3F library not found. The slower FFTPACK library will be used instead

Tags: octave, fftw

I'm compiling octave on my LFS - Linux from scratch - system.

While configuring octave, I receive a warning:

> configure: WARNING: FFTW3F library not found.  The slower FFTPACK library will be used instead.

I compiled and installed [FFTW 3.3.4](http://www.fftw.org/download.html), and then reconfigured octave, however I still receive the following messages:

> checking fftw3.h usability... yes
>
> checking fftw3.h presence... yes
>
> checking for fftw3.h... yes
>
> checking for fftw_plan_dft_1d in -lfftw3... yes
>
> checking for fftw3.h... (cached) yes
>
> checking for **fftwf**_plan_dft_1d in -l**fftw3f**... no
>
> configure: WARNING: FFTW3F library not found.  The slower FFTPACK library will be used instead.

I notice that FFTW 3.3.4 installs `libfftw3.so` but NOT `libfftw3f.so`, that's why even after installing FFTW 3.3.4, octave cannot find FFTW3F library. Now, I wonder how I can install `libfftw3f.so`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you have the **double precision** FFTW libraries (`libfftw3`) but not the **single precision** versions (`libfftw3f`). Build it again with:

```
./configure --enable-float --enable-sse && make install
```

(assuming we're talking x86 here).

This should then install the `libfftw3f` libraries next to the existing `libfftw3` libs.

Comment: These options are not correct for 5.2.0, From my experience, both fftw double precision and single precision are needed in order to get that build feature going.

Comment: Really helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, very helpful, thank you. Do you know where can I find documentation explaining the difference between libfftw3 and libfftw3f? I am not able to find it

Comment: @Chachni: it’s all in the FFTW manual, e.g. [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Precision.html#Precision).